# Log4Net web.config transform wont work

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, log4net, web.config-transform

Im trying to get a web.config transform to work for Log4Net when I publish to my Azure app, but it just never changes.  I have several other items in the transform and they work just fine.  Heres what I have

```html
<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender"  type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender"  xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
      <connectionString value="Server=production server connection details here" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong ?

This is my config transform file (live details removed)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender"  type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender"  xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
      <connectionString value="Server=server details here" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"/>
    </appender>
  </log4net>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=liveversionhere;AccountKey=liveversionhere;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage"  connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=liveversionhere;AccountKey=liveversionhere;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=liveversionhere" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="CHPDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=liveversionhere" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="elmah" connectionString="Data Source=liveversionhere" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:redirectUri" value="liveversionhere" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value=liveversionhere  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value=liveversionhere"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value=liveversionhere  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    
  </appSettings>
  
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
   
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE

I've changed the transform (see below) and it still doesn't work.  does anyone have any clue whats going on here ?  this is supposed to be pretty straightforward yet Im finding myself wasting hours of my time just to get something this basic to actually work

```html
<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
      <connectionString name="Log4NetConn" value="Server=productionsdetailshere" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: eventually managed to get this to work, I had to replace the entire log4net section  <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace">  the connectionstring section simply didnt work at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to replace the entire log4net section

the connectionstring simply didnt work

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I did some test on my side. Assuming you deploy your web application via VS, I create a new configuration named `Release.Azure` via "Build > Configuration Manager" as follows:

[image]

Then I added a web configuration file named `Web.Release.Azure.config` and configuration the content as follows:

[image]

```html
<log4net>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender"  type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender"  xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
    <connectionString value="Server=azure production server connection details here" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"/>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

**Note:** Both the value `Replace` and `SetAttributes` for the property `xdt:Transform` under the `connectionString` section could work as expected.

Use the publish wizard from VS, choose my configuration for azure under Settings as follows and deploy it to azure web app.

[image]

Additionally, I also tried to create an `applicationHost.xdt` file under `d:\home\site` of my web app via [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console), restart my azure website, then I found the transform could work. You could refer to [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples) for more details.

**UPDATE:**

The `applicationhost.xdt` would look like as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
    <log4net>
      <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender"  xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <connectionString value="Server=production server connection details here" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"/>
      </appender>
    </log4net>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That is the exact process I used, yet it never works.  I have several 'key' sections that transform perfectly well, just not log4net

Comment: It's strange. I defined the `log4net` section with the dev connectionstring in my `web.config` file, the transform could work. Have you published it to your local side and checked the `web.config` file? Additionally, please try to create an `applicationHost.xdt` file under your web app to narrow this issue.

Comment: ok, I added an applicationHost.xdt file and its still the same.  Should there be anything inside this file ?

Comment: I updated my answer and added the sample for applicationhost.xdt file. If the transform could not work in your local deployment, I assumed that you could check your web.config or update your question and add your web.config and the transform file for us to narrow this issue.

Comment: Ive installed the SlowCheetah add in and I'm able to preview my transforms, everything works as i would expect, my normal connection strings, my keys, etc.  All except Log4Net, it refuses to work

Comment: just one thing, surely If Im including an applicationHost.xdt file that would mean Id need a different one for each environment and Id have to maintain the details for each one which is the whole point of the transforms, I dont really want to have to maintain those as well

Comment: Tried everything I can think of, even using conditions, nothing works so I'm now left with the prospect of having to change these setting manually for each of my deployment environments

Comment: Ive even given the log4net connectionsting a name and then xdt:Locator="Match(name)" and it still doesn't work !! what the hell !!